# Error: Cannot find module 'flux'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, watchify

I have a JS project that requires other JS files from its parent directory.

Here is the structure of my project:

> - Web
>
>   - package.json
>   - ...
> - Core
>
>   - JS
>
>     - ...

Here is the content of package.json

```
{
  "name": "PropertyFinder",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "js/app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "flux": "^2.0.1",
    "keymirror": "~0.1.0",
    "object-assign": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^6.2.0",
    "envify": "^3.0.0",
    "reactify": "^0.15.2",
    "uglify-js": "~2.4.15",
    "watchify": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d app.js",
    "build": "browserify . -t [envify --NODE_ENV production] | uglifyjs -cm > js/bundle.min.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "Jean Lebrument",
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "reactify",
      "envify"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I run `npm start` I've these errors:

> watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d app.js
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'flux' from 'MyProject/Core/Common' Error:
>   Cannot find module 'keyMirror' from
>   '/MyProject/Core/Modules/SearchPage/Constants'

I checked and in the "node_modules" directory, the "flux" and "keymirror" directories are present.

Is this because the files from the Core directory are in the parent directory of the project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out. I had to create a `package.json` file in the Core directory with the two dependencies: `flux` and `keymirror`.